# Audio doesn't play as expected

Tags: javascript

I wrote a notify function that should play an alarm sound when conditions met and stop after confirming. But audio doesn't play and only confirm box displayed. Here is my code:

```
    function notify() {
    const alarm = new Audio('link to remote alarm audio');
    alarm.loop = true;
    alarm.play();
    if (confirm('Pause Audio?')) {
        alarm.pause();
    }
}
```

Update: Error Message -> "DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first"

Comment: Open browser console and check for errors. Maybe you are getting some kind of CORS error if the audio is from another domain.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. I have enabled CORS and get no errors on console

Comment: Post tge audio url if not possible, any other url that fails too

Comment: Size of audio file is about 1.5MB. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Try replacing `alarm.play()` by `alarm.autoplay = true` and remove temporarily the if confirm. It should play when loaded. Also check if your browser is blocking audio reproduction, most browsers blocks auto played audio. And most obvious but possible, check if your browser is reproducing any audios.

Comment: I get this error "DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first". Did some research, playing audio without user interact is not allowed in chrome

Comment: This error doesn't occurs with play()? Wherr are you calling this piece of code? Try creating a code snippet here to let us try the entire code

Comment: Solved problem by running Chrome with this code "chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required"

Comment: You solution is not recommended. Your end-user mostly won't run chrome the way you did.

Comment: It's a local bot project for personal use only so I don't need to worry about that. AFAIK there's no way to bypass this Google policy without changing Chrome setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and find out that [playing audio without user interaction is against Google rules](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). so added following internal switch to Chrome and also a 1 second timeout to give audio file enough time to load.

> Run chrome with this code -> chrome.exe
> --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required

```
function notify() {
    const alarm = new Audio('https://audio-link');
    alarm.loop = true;
    alarm.play();
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (confirm('Do you see that?')) {
            alarm.pause();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a small research, I found out that user requires to `interact` with document. Depending on your use case, if the user has interacted with document earlier, then It would work, without any errors.
(If you click on document's body, before the prompt appears, you see the audio plays).

```js
function notify() {
  const alarm = new Audio('https://freesound.org/data/previews/34/34025_302129-lq.mp3');
  alarm.loop = true;
  alarm.play();
  if (confirm('Pause Audio?')) {
    alarm.pause();
  }
}

notify();

function confirm(msg){   //For Testing Purposes
  return prompt(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still audio doesn't play. Tried your example too but stll doesn't work. Plays without any problem when I open link manually

Comment: @MM2021 I have updated my answer. Please Check.

Comment: Thanks but it's a Notify bot that supposed to notify users to comeback to page so user has no interact before audio play. Also it's better to add a timeout before if statement to give audio enough time to play. I've posted my solution too. check it out

Comment: @MM2021 Yes. This code works fine on Firefox but, not on chrome. The catch is, you can't ask every user to run chrome with that code.

Comment: That's correct. But this is a local bot project for personal use only. AFAIK there's no way to bypass this Google policy without changing Chrome setting.

Comment: @MM2021 If its for personal use, then that's OK. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting calling `alarm.load()` before `alarm.play()`

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't play without user interact first on Chrome. Check my answer. Checkout this link -> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes